# SCR based rectifier vs IGBT based rectifier

Tags: power-electronics, rectifier, igbt, thyristor, scr

I am wondering what is the difference in performance of rectifiers when used with SCR and IGBT.

I searched on internet but all i can find is that IGBT is voltage triggered and SCR is current pulse triggered and some others. But nothing about performance.

Do IGBT-based rectifiers have technical edge over SCR-based rectifiers?

Comment: Welcome! Depends. What are you trying to solve? Do you need a controllable rectifier in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

IGBTs are faster, and controllable at any time.

SCRs are slower, and can only be turned on voluntarily*, then remain latched on until current flow stops.

*There are gate-turn-off (GTO) types, which can be switched off with difficulty.

Both have comparable conduction losses.

SCRs may incur additional switching losses (e.g. forced commutation in inverters), and generally require larger support components (large value reactors and capacitors).

SCRs are available in extremely large ratings (many megawatts each); IGBTs are approaching them, but as I understand it, still inferior for the highest power applications.

There are also SiC MOSFETs and IGBTs available these days, which may be applicable in low and medium voltage applications (up to 10kV per device, perhaps more).  Data about these is scarce so I don't know much about them.  I assume they are more expensive and not available in such large ratings (i.e. 100s A), but the potential for higher efficiency (with MOSFETs) and faster switching (both types) has some promise.

(Just checked; apparently some SiC SCRs are available too, with greatly improved speed. Fascinating!)

There are few applications for SCRs at less than high-power industrial levels, and those are mainly for mains (on/off) control.  Controllable rectifiers are probably decreasingly popular due to poor power factor and the large reactors and transformers required.

Comment: "There are few applications for SCRs..."  And low-end photoflash and capacitor-discharge ignition.  Which, I'm pretty sure, is why you can still get the smallest SCRs.  But even there a FET can be superior, because you can turn off before the capacitor is fully discharged.

Comment: Indeed, last flash I took apart used an IGBT -- impressive thing, rated 400V 100A (pulsed) or something like that, at Vge(on) = 5V or so.  A bit slow (fractional µs I think it was), but a stupendous amount of power for a little DFN-8 part. Being able to turn off during a flash allows multiple flashes in rapid succession, calibrating for exposure.

Comment: Being able to turn off before the cap is fully discharged allows for faster charging -- because you're at least somewhat current limited going into the cap, and \$P = IE\$.  Or because when the cap is fully discharged, the coil current takes longer to decay.  Or both -- in either case, if you listen to that ascending whine when a photoflash charges up, that initial low-pitch part is the capacitor's charge rate being limited by the cap voltage, rather than by the time it takes to charge up the primary side of the inductor.

Comment: Not sure about cheap cameras, or attached flashes, maybe they're still the old self-oscillating kind; but mine probably used a proper regulator and flyback circuit. I never recall hearing it charge. I forget if there was a chip nearby or what.